# Typescript make Uint8Array from Number array Number[]

Tags: arrays, typescript, uint8array

```
const str = "abc";
let unicodeArray: Number[] = [];
let code = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
  code = str.charCodeAt(i);//returns number
  unicodeArray = unicodeArray.concat([code]);
}
//unicodeArray: [97, 98, 99];
let byteArray = new Uint8Array(unicodeArray);
```

new Uint8Array() gives the following error message:

No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'Number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBufferLike'.
Type 'Number[]' is missing the following properties from type 'SharedArrayBuffer': byteLength, [Symbol.species], [Symbol.toStringTag]

See Uint8Array reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array
var arr = new Uint8Array([21,31]);

May I know what is wrong?

Comment: `Number[] = [];` --> `number[] = [];`

Comment: Man you are good! Thank you